# Можно ли определить последний вызов функции? javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function my() {

    return function(value) {

        if (value > 5) return alert("GOOD");

    }
}

var user = my()

user(10) // выполняется "GOOD" 
user(8) // выполняется "GOOD"
user(3) // игнор
user(4) // игнорируется, но так как этот вызов последний, то выполняется "GOOD"
```

Можно ли как-то провернуть такое ?

Comment: А как определить последний вызов? Каковы его критерии?

Comment: а если кто-то после `user(4)`, вызовет `user(2)`? `user(4)` уже перестанет быть последним, а вывод уже был

Answer (score 0):

Только явно каким-либо образом сообщить о том, что это конец

```js
function my() {
    return function(value, isEnd) {            
        if (value > 5 || (typeof isEnd != 'undefined' && isEnd == true)) 
          console.log("value: " + value, 'isEnd: ' + isEnd);
    }
}

var user = my();

user(6);
user(1);
user(3);
user(9);
user(2, true);
```

Comment: а зачем на undefined проверять? ну и `typeof isEnd !== undefined` всегда будет `true`, так как `typeof`  возвращает строку. а любая строка не равна undefined

Comment: @Grundy `а зачем на undefined проверять` - я еще не придумал зачем.

Answer (score -1):

```html
let my = () => {
  let end = false;
  return (value) => {
    if(value > 5 || end) {
      return 'Good';
    }else {
      end = true;
    }
  }
};
```